# Is Median the right average to be used in this scenario?

Tags: forecasting, model, descriptive-statistics, median, mean

I have a large dataset in Excel relating to expenditures made by guests in a hotel over a calendar year (say, 2016). The data is by Month of Expenditure and at the granular level of each booking at the hotel for that period.

In this dataset, the columns that are of interest to me are: Month, Total Expenditure, Guest Night, Meal Plan and Market.
My aim is to calculate the average Total Expenditure Per GN by Market and for All Markets. My logic is that "expenditure" behaves a lot like "Income" and hence, the best average to be used to summarize the data would be the Median.

Thus,to get the average for a specific Month (say, March 2016), I have created a calculated column to compute the "Total Expenditure Per Guest Night" (Total Expenditure/Guest Night) for EACH booking for the month of March 2016. I then computed a the Median of the calculated column to obtain the "Median Total Expenditure Per Guest Night".

Am I on the right track? Or am I missing something critical in my process? The final aim is also to be able to use those Medians for forecasting future Total Expenditure based on Guest Nights in the books.

Comment: My best guess as to why someone has downvoted your question is that you switch between using the words "average" and "median," unaware that they are different. *Averages* have many definitions but, in your case, probably refers to the arithmetic mean, i.e., the sum of all values for a variable (an Excel column) divided by the number of observations. The *median*, on the other hand, is the midpoint between the biggest and smallest values (with an adjustment depending on whether there are odd or even numbers of observations), aka the fiftieth percentile. These are two very different metrics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is you probably want the average.  Why?  Because of the relationship between the averages and totals.  Specifically, $$\text{Average expenditure (nightly)} \times \text{Number of nights} = \text{Total Expenditure}.$$
Presumably when forecasting you will know the number of nights the guest will be staying, so your unknown is the average nightly expenditure.  You could use a different estimator for the average nightly expenditure than average nightly expenditure found in your dataset. However, it sounds like you want to do something simple, and unless you have a reason to do something else, using the sample average is a reasonable starting point.

Say you want to make total expenditure forecasts for the New York market in March.  Here's a possible approach:

1. Add up all the expenditures in your dataset made in the New York market in March.
2. Add up all the guest nights in your dataset made in the New York market in March.
3. Divide #1 by #2 to get an estimate of the average expenditures per night in the New York market in March.
4. To forecast the expenditures for a new booking in New York in March, multiply the estimate of average expenditures per night found in #3 by the number of nights in the new booking.

You've probably already realized this won't always work well.  Holidays, for example, will not be well captured using such an approach.  If you need better forecasts, a more sophisticated model may be necessary.

As an aside to preempt future confusion, I probably should point out that usually when statisticians speak of the "average" they are referring to the arithmetic mean.  Using this more specific definition, while both the arithmetic mean and the median are measures of central tendency, the median is not a type of average.

Comment: The median is not a type of average? Could you explain a bit more about this? The median is listed alongside all the other types of averages wherever I look (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average, http://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm)

Comment: I think the OP means that the median is a measure of central tendency.

Comment: Isn't the arithmetic mean also a measure of central tendency though (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency#Measures_of_central_tendency)? Sorry for being pedantic but I've never seen anywhere that the median isn't considered a type of average.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I edited the answer to (hopefully) clarify what I was trying to convey.